# Реализация жеста "бросок" в CustomView

Tags: android-sdk, android

Пытаюсь реализовать жест "бросок" или "fling" в *CustomView*, но точка которую я рисую для тестирования , часто возвращается в исходное положение, что я делаю не так?

Вот код:

```
public class MoveView extends View {
final float startX;
final float startY;

private Paint p;

private Scroller scroller;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public MoveView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    startX = 400;
    startY = 640;

    p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());
    scroller = new Scroller(context);
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        int oldX = getScrollX();
        int oldY = getScrollY();
        int x = scroller.getCurrX();
        int y = scroller.getCurrY();
        scrollTo(x, y);

        if (oldX != getScrollX() || oldY != getScrollY()) {
            onScrollChanged(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), oldX, oldY);
            AppLog.d("computeScroll = " + getScrollX() + " : " + getScrollY() + " : " + oldX + " : " + oldY);
        }

        invalidate();
    } else {
        AppLog.d("computeScroll = 2");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        AppLog.d("onScroll = " + distanceX + " : " + distanceY);
        scrollBy((int)distanceX, (int)distanceY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        AppLog.d("onScroll = " + getScrollX() + " : " + getScrollY() + ":"+ velocityX + " : " + velocityY + " : " + getWidth() + " : " + getHeight());
        scroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), -(int) velocityX, -(int) velocityY, 0, getWidth(), 0, getHeight());
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, 8, p);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится:

```
public class MoveView extends View {
    float startX;
    float startY;
    float finishX;
    float finishY;

    private Paint p;
    private Paint textPaint;

    private OverScroller mScroller;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private int offset = 0;

    public MoveView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        startX = 0;
        startY = 0;
        finishX = 100;
        finishY = 1280;

        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setTextSize(40);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new         GestureListener(this));
        mScroller = new OverScroller(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // called when the GestureListener detects scroll
    public void scroll(int distanceX) {
        AppLog.d("scroll, distanceX = " + distanceX + ", offset = " + offset);
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        offset += distanceX;
        checkOffset();
        invalidate();
    }

    // called when the GestureListener detects fling
    public void fling(int velocityX) {
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        mScroller.fling(offset, 0, -velocityX, 0, 0, 12800, 0, 0, 50, 0);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void checkOffset() {
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //computeScrollOffset() returns true if a fling is in progress
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            offset = mScroller.getCurrX();
            postInvalidateDelayed(30);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if(i % 5 == 0) {
                p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if(i % 4 == 0) {
                p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if(i % 3 == 0) {
                p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(i % 2 == 0) {
                p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                p.setColor(Color.RED);
            }

            canvas.drawRect(startX + 80 * i - offset, startY, finishX + 80 * i - offset, finishY, p);
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i), startX + 80 * i - offset, (startY + finishY) / 2, textPaint);
        }
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private MoveView mMoveView;

        public GestureListener(MoveView moveView) {
            mMoveView = moveView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            mMoveView.scroll((int) distanceX);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            mMoveView.fling((int) velocityX);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```